# Java: Convert an instance of the legacy type Dictionary to a Map

Tags: java, collections

I'm calling a library that, for API compatibility reasons, returns an instance of type `java.util.Dictionary`, but I want to have an instance implementing `java.util.Map`.

How can I easily convert an `java.util.Dictionary` instance to a `java.util.Map` instance?

Comment: If the Dictionary happens to be a Hashtable, you can simply use the copy constructor (after a cast).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Guava and Java 8:

```
Iterator<String> keysIter = Iterators.forEnumeration(dict.keys());
Map<String, Object> dictCopy = Maps.toMap(keysIter, dict::get);
```

Alternative in pure Java 8:

```
List<String> keys = Collections.list(dict.keys());
Map<String, Object> dictCopy = keys.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), dict::get));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I could program this conversion myself (under the additional assumption that the `Dictionary` has generic type arguments).

Add the method

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> addDictionaryToMap(Dictionary<K, V> source, Map<K, V> sink) {
    for (Enumeration<K> keys = source.keys(); keys.hasMoreElements();) {
        K key = keys.nextElement();
        sink.put(key, source.get(key));
    }
    return sink;
}
```

and call it for example with `addDictionaryToMap(dict, new HashMap<String, String>())`.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer following a `public static <K, V> Map<K, V> valueOf(Dictionary<K, V> dictionary)` style of naming this kind of methods. And I would ask [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) guys to add it to their [Maps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) class.

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> valueOf(Dictionary<K, V> dictionary) {
  if (dictionary == null) {
    return null;
  }
  Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>(dictionary.size());
  Enumeration<K> keys = dictionary.keys();
  while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    K key = keys.nextElement();
    map.put(key, dictionary.get(key));
  }
  return map;
}
```

Comment: How would you implement your method? There are two open question that you'll need to solve: Choosing the map implementation type, and dealing with type erasure. My implementation avoids these issues.

Comment: The only standard (= shipped with JDK) implementation of the Dictionary that I know is Hashtable which is, by the way, deprecated in favour of HashMap. As far as I understand, Dictionary does not guarantee any iteration order. That's why I would go for the HashMap as the return value. For the implementation, there is no other way than what you proposed, i.e. iterating over elements.

Comment: The implementation doesn't need to create a `Dictionary` instance. The question is which implementation of `Map` to pick. The JRE comes with different implementations. Still, `HashMap` is probably a sensible default.

Comment: Type erasure is in fact not a problem, `new HashMap<K, V>()` works. (Arrays of generic types would be a problem, but not one to be solved here.)

Answer (score 1):

One interesting way to implement that is with the view approach, which allows you to have the `Dictionary` and the `Map` linked together and both fully-functional. As shown in the following code example:

```
Dictionary<String, String> dict = new Hashtable<>();

dict.put("PT", "Portugal");
dict.put("CH", "Switzerland");
System.out.println(dict);

Map<String, String> map = MapUtils.asMap(dict);
System.out.println(map);

map.remove("CH");
dict.put("UK", "United Kingdom");
System.out.println(dict);
System.out.println(map);

map.clear();
System.out.println(dict);
System.out.println(map);
```

The implementation would be something like this:

```
public class MapUtils {
    public static  <K, V> Map<K, V> asMap(Dictionary<K, V> dict) {
        return new AbstractMap<K, V>() {
            @Override
            public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
                return new AbstractSet<Entry<K, V>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
                        return new Iterator<Entry<K, V>>() {
                            private Enumeration<K> keys = dict.keys();
                            private Enumeration<V> elements = dict.elements();
                            private K k = null;

                            @Override
                            public boolean hasNext() {
                                return keys.hasMoreElements();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public Entry<K, V> next() {
                                k = keys.nextElement();
                                return new SimpleEntry<>(k,
                                        elements.nextElement());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void remove() {
                                if (k == null) {
                                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                                }
                                dict.remove(k);
                                k = null;
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int size() {
                        return dict.size();
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return dict.size();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
                return dict.get(key) != null;
            }

            @Override
            public V get(Object key) {
                return dict.get(key);
            }

            @Override
            public V put(K key, V value) {
                return dict.put(key, value);
            }

            @Override
            public V remove(Object key) {
                return dict.remove(key);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Some overridden methods are optional, but I implemented them for performance reasons.